# Mongoose/Express authorisation on http verbs

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a node.js REST service running on mongoose and express. I'm also using merse to get my routing set up.

What I'd like to achieve now are the following types of sceanrios:

```
Scenario I: e.g. blogpost
- GET -> no authentication required
- POST/PUT/DELETE -> authentication required

Scenario II: e.g. user
- GET -> authentication required
- POST/PUT/DELETE -> authentication required plus username of logged in user has to match
```

I've allready had a look at everyauth and mongoose-auth, but couldn't find anything which would give me this kind of control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Forget about everyauth. This library is an overkill, imho. Implementing authentication is quite simple actually, follow the schema:

1. User passes `username` and `password` to the server;
2. Server gets `username` and `password` and checks in DB whether there is a user with that `password`. If there is no user, just respond with an error;
3. We have a user, now use built-in session mechanism of Express. Call `req.session.regenerate` and in the callback do `req.session.userID = user.id`. Express will automatically send the cookie to the user;
4. Create a middleware (has to fire **before** any other request handler), which basically searches the database for `req.session.userID`. If it finds one, then store it in `req`, i.e. `req.user = user`;
5. In a view you simply check whether `req.user` variable is set. If it is, then we are authenticated. And you're done!

ad 1+2) To make authentication safe, you should use some cryptography (and/or HTTPS). For example, the password should be held in DB in two parts: `salt` and `hash`. `salt` is generated randomly (at the time of registration) and `hash = hash_it(pwd, salt)`, where `hash_it` is some hashing algorithm (for example: MD5 or SHA256).

Now client side authentication can be made in several steps (only if you can use JavaScript):

1. Server sends random `new_salt` to the login page (or generate one in JavaScript, there is no need to hide generating algorithm);
2. User sends AJAX request `give me salt for user X` and server responds with the `salt` stored in DB (the `salt` is public);
3. On response hash `pwd` with `salt` and then hash the result again with `new_salt`, store it in variable `hpwd`;
4. Client sends `username`, `hpwd` and `new_salt` to the server;
5. Server gets `pwd` from DB for `username`, hashes `pwd` with `new_salt` and compares the result to `hpwd` (note: you do not store `new_salt`).

This method is nice, since every time you log in a random (from the external point of view) data flows through net, even though the `username` and the `password` is the same.

This is important, because `password` leak is a serious thing. Not because someone can break your app's account (that's a minor damage, unless you're a bank - but then you wouldn't ask such questions :D ). Mostly because people tend to use the same passwords for multiple sites, including bank accounts.

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer. The way I understand it (and to keep my code slim)  would be to create the middleware you mention in 4.) and handle the route filtering there. So if url and verb matches a certain pattern, I can allow or deny..

Comment: @AyKarsi Yes, that's one possibility, you can do that. Or you can handle this in the final route (remember about storing `req.user`). It's up to you. :)

Comment: Agreed that everyauth is overkill.  That's the reason I developed [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), which is a middleware solution that does almost exactly what you describe in steps 1-5, along with options for handling common use cases.  Strategies allow you to extend it with additional capabilities, such as third-party login using Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Comment: Does Passport do cryptography? Or is that something that needs to be done independently?

Comment: not sure if anyone will see this question, but why do we hash the result _again_ with the new_salt (step 3 on the client)?

Comment: @arieljake So that random-like data (from external point of view) flows through the net (`new_salt` is random). Otherwise each time you type the same password the same hash will go through the net. Additional layer of security.