# Architecture for login system on MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I'm developing a web app on the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and node.js). I'm developing a login system, and will also have some of the Angular routes protected so that only logged-in users can access them. I'm trying to think of the best way to approach the architecture of this.

I'm thinking of the current workflow:

- User logs in via AngularJS form, which sends an http POST to an Express endpoint. The endpoint validates the user against the database, and responds with an OAuth token as well as a cookie. Both are stored in the mongo database for later validation.
- Once AngularJS receives the login response, it stores the received cookie using ng-cookies, and stores the OAuth token in a User service.
- Every time the route changes in AngularJS now, the User service is used to make sure that the cookie is still legitimate by comparing it to cookies in the mongo database (this would be an API call using Angular's resolve... would this create a noticeable lag?)
- When a user clicks "log out" or the cookie expires, the cookie and OAuth token are both deleted from the database and will no longer be valid.

Does this approach make sense? Is it secure, and will it be relatively efficient/quick in execution?

Comment: Makes sense, you can also make use of sessions, so you're not checking the DB every time you change the route.

Comment: Would the sessions be managed by Express? And then on route change I'd still make an API call but it wouldn't be to check the DB?

Comment: Yep, `req.session` -- Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218725/working-with-sessions-in-express-js -- Or you can checkout HTML5 `sessionStorage`

Comment: And a much better blog post about Express sessions: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

Comment: take a look at http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up combining my original workflow with Express's auth example, seen [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js). It is as follows:

- When user initially loads the app, an http call is made to an Express endpoint that checks if a session exists already for the user. If so, the user is stored in `$rootScope` and considered logged in.
- Any time the AngularJS route changes, the same endpoint is accessed. Route protection was specified in a way similar to that described [here](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app). If the endpoint ever returns that no session exists, `$rootScope.user` is unset (if it needs to be), and the user is redirected to the login page.
- When the login form is processed, it posts to an Express endpoint. The endpoint retrieves the user from the mongoDB (if it exists), and attempts to hash the password. If it's a match, the user's session is set, stored in the mongo DB, and the endpoint returns the `user` object (used to store in the $rootScope as previously mentioned).
- Any time any further endpoints are accessed, the functions are first passed through the `restrict` function which ensures that a session exists before sending any data to the client. It returns a `401` if no session exists, which is then handled on the Angular side using [this HTTP interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) to unset `$rootScope.user` and redirect to the login screen.
- When the user clicks "log out" on the Angular side, the session is unset and deleted from the mongo DB, `$rootScope.user` is set to null, and the user is redirected back to the front page.