# PHP session variable equivalent for the mean stack

Tags: php, session, mean-stack

When I first started learning PHP, you could use `$_SESSION` array to store information and use it on multiple sites, like setting a username of someone who has logged in.

Is there something like that for the MEAN stack?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185315/architecture-for-login-system-on-mean-stack

Answer (score 0):

Module to use `express-session`

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
```

initialize

```
app.use(session({secret: 'something'}));
```

sessionVariable in the below code is equivalent to $_SESSION in php.

```
  var sessionVariable;
    app.get('/',function(req,res){
    sessionVariable=req.session;

    sessionVariable.email = 'test@test.com;
    sessionVariable.username = 'test'; 
    });
```

Comment: If i have this code in one file, and one access this variable in another file, what would i have to include in the files ?

Comment: can you elaborate it more ?