# How can we revoke (remove) a particular token from firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

My goal is to logout a user from the web app in the user is logged in another browser.
Example: If the user is logged in chrome and now the user is trying to log in firefox then the user should be logged out from chrome.
Is there a solution to remove only that particular token from firebase

I have already used revokeRefreshTokens method to revoke the tokens. But that won't work because this method will remove all the tokens. Which means also the token in mobile app. So if the user logs into a browser then the user will be logged out from the app. The below code is the one I used

admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid);

Is there a solution to remove a user token alone from firebase. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the session. PassportJS have such functions. See this post:

[Express.js + Passport.js : How to restrict multiple login by the same user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144827/express-js-passport-js-how-to-restrict-multiple-login-by-the-same-user)

Since you are trying to do that with Firebase, here try this:

[How to prevent simultaneous logins of the same user with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321234/how-to-prevent-simultaneous-logins-of-the-same-user-with-firebase)