# how i can save express session when i'm using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I am using Express for my Back end of my React app when i set a session in a page and redirect to another page of my web app the session deleted

Here my express code :

```
async function createUser(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let parameters = req.body
    let user = await models.User.create({
      displayName: parameters.displayName,
      phone: parameters.phone,
      sex: parameters.sex,
      password: parameters.password,
  })
  req.session.user = user.dataValues;
  res.json({
    status: 'success',
    user,
  })
}
```

and here is my react code :

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  request.post('/newuser',{
    displayName:this.state.name,
    phone:this.state.phone,
    password:this.state.password,
    sex:this.state.sex
  })
  .then(function(response){
    this.props.authenticate(true)
    this.setState({
      auth:true
    })
  }.bind(this))
}
```

and here is my react render method:

```
render(){
  if(this.state.auth) 
    return <Redirect to='/profile' />;
}
```

with all this describes when i redirected to the profile page i dont have any session and all hope is gone :))

please help me solve this problem .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with Sessions in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218725/working-with-sessions-in-express-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use axios for sending request you should do this :

**In Front (React) :**
You should set withCredentials: true in axios setting like this :

```
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../../config'

const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.url,
  timeout: 20000,
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default request
```

**In Back (Node/Express) :** you should add this code the the cors

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({
  origin:['http://localhost:9520']//your front url,
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true
}))
```

I figured it out by searching, Thanks for not helping though :))